# WebBrowser problems - InvalidOperationException when Navigating

Tags: c#, browser

I have got a multi-threaded application which uses a WebBrowser control hosted in a simple WPF window.

On the first time I create the window and display it - everything is fine.
However - when I try to open it more times (usually on the third time...) I get and Invalid Operation Exception, when trying to call the Navigate method of the WebBrowser.

I have tried reading some about it and I think that it is related to the DEP, and the COM object behind the WebBrowser.

I thought that maybe it is related to the previous WebBrowsers, so I treid to dispose it in different ways, such as:

```
brws.DocumentCompleted -= new System.Windows.Forms.
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(brws_DocumentCompleted);
brws.Stop();
brws.DocumentText = "";
this.brws.Dispose();
```

But it does not help...

Maybe anyone saw this error and knows how to solve it?

Here is the exact error data:

> Exception was unhandled: System.AccessViolationException:
>   System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
>
> at- 
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IWebBrowser2.Navigate2(Object&
>   U RL, Object& flags, Object& targetFrameName, Object& postData,
>   Object& headers)
>
> at-  System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.PerformNavigate2(Object& URL,
>   Object& fla gs, Object& targetFrameName, Object& postData, Object&
>   headers)
>
> at-  System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.PerformNavigateHelper(String
>   urlString, B oolean newWindow, String targetFrameName, Byte[]
>   postData, String headers)
>
> at-  System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.Navigate(String urlString)
>
> at-  Slider.HtmlWindow..ctor(String url) at-
>   D:\rapid\Projects\HTMLSlider\Slide r\HtmlWindow.xaml.cs:Line 24
>
> at-  Slider.Program.<>c_*DisplayClasse.b*_3() at-
>   D:\rapid\Projects \HTMLSlider\Slider\Program.cs:line 123
>
> at-  System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>
> at-  System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>
> at-  System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: race condition, stop and DocumentText are asynchronous calls and you did not want for the background threads to finish.

Comment: Do you mean the webbrowser's background threads? how do I wait for them to finish? (How do I know if they're running...)

Comment: Do stuff in DocumentCompleted. Note setting DocumentText triggers another Navigate and you need to wait for another DocumentCompleted. Do not access the object after calling Dispose.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a solution to this.

Probably there is an internal problem when disposing one WebBrowser in an app and then creating another one.

My solution was to modify my code to re-use the WebBrowsers instead of creating new ones.
Now, after there are no WebBrowsers Disposals, there are no problems.